# Splitting SQL columns by delimiter in SQL Server 12

Tags: sql, sql-server, split, delimiter

I have a table called `my_table` in `myDB` SQL Server database.

`my_table` contains:

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| baz-12:1234:bom | bim |
| baz-34:5678:bom | bim |

What select statement would return a column containing the third set of values '1234' in row 1 and '5678' in row 2?

I am using SQL Server 12.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT STRING_SPLIT(foo) 
FROM my_table
```

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Or perhaps SQL Server 2014, which is version 12?

Comment: 2012 or 2014 is irrilevant, String_split will need SQL Server 2016

Comment: At least, I suppose, 2014 is still in (extended) support, @user_0 . 2012's support has completely expired now